# std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() undefined in Visual C++ 2015

Tags: c++

The following code produces an error: `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` undefined error.

Using `numeric_limits<double>::epsilon` also produces this error.

```
#ifndef _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#endif // !_USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

class plusCartesianPoly {

public:

    static bool isClose(double a, double b)
    {
        if (fabs(a-b) <= std::numeric_limits::epsilon())
            return true;

        return(false);
    }
};
```

Comment: `std::numeric_limits` is defined in `<limits>`, not `<limits.h>`.

Comment: General rule of thumb: never user `*.h` includes for things from `std`.

Comment: OT, It could be a better idea to scale epsilon somehow. See the example code in the [reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon).

Comment: Thanks most kindly - very useful comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`numeric_limits` is declared in `limits`, not `limits.h` which is the C version of `climits` (by the way, `math.h` is the C version of `cmath`):

```
#ifndef _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#endif // !_USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

class plusCartesianPoly {

public:

    static bool isClose(double a, double b)
    {
        if (std::fabs(a-b) <= std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())
            return true;

        return(false);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

`<limits.h>` contains the macro-type limits from the C standard library

You need `<limits>` to use the C++ standard library functions.